# Button with different width on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-5

I want to increase the size of a custom button if the user is using an iPhone 5.

This is what I have in my .m file

```
//.m File
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        int varWidth = 228;
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        int varWidth = 272;
    }
}

....

[newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 40.0, 228, 80.0)];
```

But I want something like this:

```
[newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 40.0, varWidth, 80.0)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `varWidth` out of it's scope.

```
int varWidth;

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        varWidth = 228;
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        varWidth = 272;
    }
}

....

[newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 40.0, varWidth, 80.0)];
```

Comment: In that case the width of the button will always be 228, but i want it to be 272 if the users has an iPhone 5

Comment: Whoo!! You solved my question, but note that varWidth must end with '.0'

Comment: @Maarten1909 for that you have to take `varWidth` as `float` rather than `integer`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
       [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 40.0, 228.0, 80.0)];
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
       [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 40.0, 272, 80.0)];
    }
}
```

Why not do this way?

Another suggestion:

Use #define.

For example:

```
#define iPhone5width 272
#define iPhone4width 228

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
       [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 40.0, iPhone4width, 80.0)];
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
       [newButton setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0, 40.0, iPhone5width, 80.0)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I have more than one button, and this way does work but it my code will get very messy

Comment: have a look at the edited code... in this way, can add more buttons and if u need to change the width, you have to edit only one place, #define

Comment: Still, if there are 10 buttons this means having 20 `setFrame:` lines instead of 10, or 30 if there is a separate section for iPads... And changing a button's position requires editing each `setFrame:` call for the button separately.

Answer (score 1):

The Best and Short way, For check  device is `iPhone 5 or iPhone5 < (Less Then)`.
For get this you need to write following code in your `.pch` file of project.

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

This Like check device, is it iPhone5 or not.

And you need to write only one condition for manage it

```
if( IS_IPHONE_5 )
        // set or put code related to iPhone 5.
else
        // set or put code related to less then iPhone 5.
```